# Layout shows only CheckBox, does not show the ImageView etc

Tags: java, android, xml, android-checkbox

I have added layout and classes below. The problem I am having is that although I have specified it in the layout, I cannot see the ImageView and TextViews other than checkbox. Layout shows only **CheckBox**, does not show the **ImageView**, the **TextView** and **second TextView**!

Project page CheckBox clicked:

[image: project page CheckBox clicked]

Project page on emulator:

[image: project page on emulator]

Project page in AndroidStudio:

[image: project page in AndroidStudio]

Drink Activity Layout is
**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.hfad.starbuzz.DrinkActivity" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/photo"
android:layout_width="190dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/description"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<CheckBox android:id="@+id/favorite"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/favorite"
android:onClick="onFavoriteClicked" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Drink Activity:**

```
package com.hfad.starbuzz;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DrinkActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKID = "drinkId";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

        //Getting a drink from an intent
        int drinkId = (Integer) Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getInt(EXTRA_DRINKID);

        //Creating a cursor
        SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("DRINK",
                    new String[]{"NAME","DESCRIPTION","IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID","FAVORITE"},
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[]{Integer.toString(drinkId)},null,null,null);

        

        //Move to the first entry in the cursor
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //Get the drink details from the cursor
        String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
        String descriptionText = cursor.getString(1);
        int photoId = cursor.getInt(2);
        boolean isFavorite = (cursor.getInt(3) == 1);
        //Filling in the name of the drink
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(nameText);
        //Filling in the description of the drink
        TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        description.setText(descriptionText);
        //Filling the drink image
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        photo.setImageResource(photoId);
        photo.setContentDescription(nameText);
        //Filling the Flag for Your Favorite Drink
        CheckBox favorite = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        favorite.setChecked(isFavorite);
        }
            

        cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                    " unavailable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    //Database refresh on click of a checkbox
    public void onFavoriteClicked(View view){
        int drinkId = (Integer) Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getInt(EXTRA_DRINKID);
        //Getting the value of a checkbox
        CheckBox favorite = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put("FAVORITE", favorite.isChecked());
        //Retrieving a database link and updating the FAVORITE column
        SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.update("DRINK",
                    drinkValues,
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[] {Integer.toString(drinkId)});
            db.close();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**StarbuzzDatabaseHelper:**

```
package com.hfad.starbuzz;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class StarbuzzDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "starbuzz"; // Database name
    //Increasing the version number means that the SQLite Assistant will know to update the database.
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 12; // Database version and version number.
    StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    //The onCreate () method is called when the database is first created;
    //We use it to create a table and insert data
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        updateMyDatabase(db, 0, DB_VERSION);
    }

    //The updateMyDatabase () method is called from onUpgrade () with parameters passed.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        updateMyDatabase(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    //It is necessary to insert the data of several drinks,
    //so we created a separate method for inserting.
    private static void insertDrink(SQLiteDatabase db, String name,
                                    String description, int resourceId) {
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put("NAME", name);
        drinkValues.put("DESCRIPTION", description);
        drinkValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", resourceId);
        db.insert("DRINK", null, drinkValues);
    }

    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 1) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DRINK (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "NAME TEXT, "
                    + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, "
                    + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER);");
            insertDrink(db, "Latte", "Espresso and steamed milk", R.drawable.latte);
            insertDrink(db, "Cappuccino", "Espresso, hot milk and steamed-milk foam",
                    R.drawable.cappuccino);
            insertDrink(db, "Filter", "Our best drip coffee", R.drawable.filter);
        }
        //This code is executed if the user already has version 1 of the database installed
        if (oldVersion >= 2) {
        }
        //Code for adding a new column
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your query returning any data? You might want to check the output of cursor.getCount().

Also if you go into Developer Options of your device you can see an option called "Show Layout Bounds". It will show you where your view elements are on the screen.

Comment: When i open the drink activity layout, Toast returns Text " unavailable" when I click the Checkbox, Toast returns to me "Database unavailable" .                                                       I took your advice and used "Show layout bounds" on my Device its show me, everything like on picture above (Project page in AndroidStudio)  ImageView, TextView and second TextView are empty inside !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, in public class StarbuzzDatabaseHelper

''''

```
private static final int DB_VERSION = 12;
```

''''

```
change to: private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
```

''''

```
 if (oldVersion >= 2) {
    }
```

''''

```
change to: if (oldVersion < 2) {
         db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DRINK ADD COLUMN FAVORITE NUMERIC;");
    }
```

''''